# How to keep cwac video preview aspect ratio consistent between pre and during recording

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture, commonsware-cwac

I'm using the cwac-camera library on android with `useFullBleedPreview() == true`.
When I start recording a video, the aspect ratio of the preview changes. It also stays like that even after I stop recording until I restart/reload the camera fragment.

Is there a way to keep the aspect ratio of the preview consistent between non-recording and recording?

If not, is there a way to set enable/disable the video recording preview aspect ratio before the recording starts? This way I could have a video mode which changes the preview aspect ratio and the user can see in advance what the preview during recording will be.

using version 6.2 of the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is totally correct but this seems to have solved the problem for me. (Need to test on more devices):

In the class extending the `SimpleCameraHost` or implementing `CameraHost` add the following:

```
@Override
public Camera.Size getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo(int displayOrientation, int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters, Camera.Size deviceHint) {
    return CameraUtils.getOptimalPreviewSize(displayOrientation, width, height, parameters);
}
```

Comment: "Don't know if this is totally correct" -- if it works, it is totally by accident, will be unsuitable for most apps that do both still photos and video recording (which will want a bigger picture size), and probably does not work on all devices.

Comment: I updated it to getOptimalPreviewSize which seems to work as well. If I use the GetLargestSize I get a `setParameters failed` RuntimeException. If I use the BestAspectRatio, the preview image is stretched.

Comment: "I updated it to getOptimalPreviewSize which seems to work as well" -- that too is by circumstance and may not work on all devices. Basically what you're doing is noticing that you have a hole in your wall, moving a picture to hang over the hole, then concluding that all holes in walls can be solved by covering the hole with a picture. That may solve *your* hole, and it may solve the holes that some other people have. But if a shark busts through your wall, you're gonna need a bigger picture. :-)

Comment: I understand :) Not perfect, but at least I put some bunny ears on the shark. (it looks better than without it).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to keep the aspect ratio of the preview consistent between non-recording and recording?

Your problem is a variation on [this issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/71). There is no known workaround at this time, though I hold out some hope that some changes that I make in 0.7 will help here.

> If not, is there a way to set enable/disable the video recording preview aspect ratio before the recording starts?

Not that I am aware of.

Comment: Any estimates on when 0.7 will be released?

Comment: @MikeT: Late August or very early September.

Comment: see the solution I've found.